# Equivalence of categories between normal subgroups of G and congruence relations on G

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $\mathcal{N}$ the collection of normal subgroups of $G$ and $\mathcal{C}$ the collection congruence relations on  $G$. In my group theory class we showed there is a bijective correspondence between $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ via 
$$N \mapsto \left[ a\sim b \iff a^{-1}b \in N \right]$$
and
$${\sim} \mapsto [1]$$

Can this be extended to an equivalence of categories?

The difficulty I’m having is understanding the morphisms. I tried taking $\hom(\mathcal{N})$ to consist of group homorphisms $\phi : M \to N$. And $\hom(\mathcal{C})$ to consist of maps $f:(G,\sim_1) \to (G,\sim_2)$ such that $a \sim_1 b$ implies $f(a) \sim_2 f(b)$. But I don't see where these morphisms should be mapped to.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to me that you can set

$$\operatorname{hom}(\sim_1,\sim_2)=\begin{cases}
\{\langle\sim_1,\sim_2\rangle\},&\text{if }{\sim_1}\supseteq{\sim_2}\\
\varnothing,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

and

$$\operatorname{hom}(N_1,N_2)=\begin{cases}
\operatorname{id}_{N_1},&\text{if }N_1\le N_2\\
\varnothing,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

much as is done in turning a partial order into a category. I’m not sure that it’s at all interesting, but it does seem to work.

Comment: Could you please explain what $\{\langle\sim_1,\sim_2\rangle\}$ means? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @Bysshed: The set whose only element is the ordered pair $\langle\sim_1,\sim_2\rangle$.

Comment: This technically works, but is probably not what the OP *really* (subconsciously) has in mind.

Comment: @Stefan: I expect that you’re probably right, but I thought that it should at least be mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I won't argue with that.

Comment: Wait, sorry! I was confused. This works just fine! The standard construction I had in mind gives you equivalent preorders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was hoping to keep homorphisms the same as group homorphisms. This example seems too simple, for example normal subgroups of $G$ would be isomorphic iff they are equal.

Comment: @Bysshed The right kind of sameness of *sub*groups is *not* group isomorphism but equality. Consider how a group may be embedded into another group in multiple ways. - There is also a categorical explanation of the phenomenon: It's isomorphism in a slice category (in our case we have a skeleton of a subcategory of $G/\mathsf{Grp}$)

Comment: @StefanPerko I don't follow you. If we consider the quarternions, why don't I want $\langle i \rangle$, $\langle j \rangle$ and $\langle k \rangle$ to be isomorphic?

Comment: @Bysshed They are isomorphic as groups, they aren't as subgroups. That's not how subobjects work. You need to take into consideration how they embed into the entire group. You can arrive at this idea by purely categorical means completely ignoring the fact, that these things are structured sets, too.

Comment: @Bysshed I know this sounds strange at first, but e.g. look at the Sylow theorem saying (not in the case of $Q8$, I just don't any other example fitting here atm) that the number of $p$-sylow subgoups of $G$ is $|G : N_G(P)|$, where $N_G(P)$ is the normalizer of some $p$-sylow subgroup $P$. That's false if you just identify isomorphic subgroups.